# Compiling Basic C++ Class

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to compile a very basic C++ program and there is something wrong. Whatever it is, I'm sure it's very obvious. I have three very short files.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Player rob;
    cout << "Iran" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player {
public:
    Player();
private:
    int score;
};

#endif
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player(){
    score = 0;
}
```

The command I'm using to compile is `g++ main.cpp -o main`
And the error I'm being issued by the compiler is:

```
/tmp/ccexA7vk.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Player::Player()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Note: All these files are in the same directory.

Comment: Try compiling the `player.cpp` file as well... The compiler cannot automagically just find the function body in non-compiled file.

Comment: Looks like you aren't compiling Player.cpp. Give `g++ main.cpp Player.cpp -o main` a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Ahh yeah you all are correct. I just needed to have the Player.cpp included in there as well. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are not feeding Player.cpp into compiler. You should give all the cpp files to the compiler.

```
g++ main.cpp Player.cpp -o main
```